# How to know if the number of divisors in a determined range for a number is odd or even

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I would like to know if the number of divisors for the number in a determined range is odd or even without counting the divisors, I think the question is a little tad fuzzy, thus, I will supply the question with an example .
Suppose we have n = 7 and b = 24, Is the number of divisors for b in range 1 to n odd or even ?
in our example we have : 1,2,3,4,6 then we have five divisors, so the number is **odd**, we just omitted the rest divisors { 8, 12, 24 } because they are out of the range .
Is there such a method to solve this matter ? 
Thank you !

Comment: number of divisors is even unless the number itself is a perfect square.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question posed, except when $n=b$. I wanted to write an answer that an efficient algorithm for this problem would solve integer factorization, but on further reflection I don't think it does.

Comment: @MJD, I have no idea what question was posed. The part I got had to do with counting divisors of numbers. Well, looking again, it seems the OP wants to count the divisors of some $b,$ but only up to some smaller bound $n.$ I don't know how you could do that without factoring, a single prime factor might be just above or just below the bound $n.$

Comment: The linked duplicate points out that an efficient algorithm to solve this problem would efficiently factor numbers of the form $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime, so would kill prime-related cryptography just as well as a general factoring algorithm would.